# Google Sheet, Concatenate, Add and Append?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm not sure this is possible...
I have a list of users whith devices (Tablet, Phone etc) in various states (Wiped, Locked etc).

Is it possible to have a formula that can take those states in each cell, merge to a single cell but also count up if there are duplicates and add the count figure to the cell and then place that in a different tab in the sheet using an xlookup?

At the moment I'm doing this by hand, the concatenate is simple but I just end up with this in a cell
Pending Wipe, Locked, Deprovisioned, Locked, Locked, Wiped
I want to remove the duplicates and jsut have it show as in the second screenshot.

Here is the list
[image]

And here is the ouput I'm looking for
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=JOIN(", ",UNIQUE(BYROW(FILTER(C2:C,A2:A=E2),LAMBDA(rw,rw & " x" & COUNTIFS(A2:A,E2,C2:C,rw)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thats really nice  
If the ist (cols A, B, C in your screenshot) are on Sheet2 but the user (Dave in col E) is also on Sheet1 can the joined up data be shown on sheet 1?

Comment: @fission Yes. Just use shee1 name in-front of cell ranges like `Sheet2!C2:C`.

Comment: Also if it helps then please mark the answer as solved (tick mark it).